# How can I get a cumulative product with Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I want to calculate the cumulative product across rows in Snowflake.

Basically I have monthly rates that multiplied accumulate across time.

(Some databases have the `product()` SQL function for that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A trick suggested by Sterling Paramore: Add logs, and then exponentiate it:

```sql
with data as (select $1 x from values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))

select x
    , sum(x) over(order by x) sum
    , exp(sum(ln(x)) over(order by x)) mult
from data
```

[image]

Comment: this is really nice.

Comment: Beautiful! For those curious: due to the property `ln(a*b) = ln(a) + ln(b)` the following is true `exp(ln(a) + ln(b)) = a*b`, since `exp(ln(x)) = x` for any `x>=0`.

Answer (score 1):

If a built-in function doesn't exist, it's usually possible to roll something custom using a [User-Defined Table Function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html).

In this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CUMULATIVE_PRODUCT(VALUE double)
    RETURNS TABLE (PRODUCT double)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS '{
        initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
           this.cumulativeProduct = 1;
        },
        processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
           this.cumulativeProduct = this.cumulativeProduct*row.VALUE;
           rowWriter.writeRow({PRODUCT: this.cumulativeProduct});
        }
    }';
```

Example table:

```
create temp table sample_numbers as (
select 1 as index, 5.1::double as current_value
    union all
select 2 as index, 4.3::double as current_value
    union all
select 3 as index, 3.7::double as current_value
    union all
select 4 as index, 3.9::double as current_value
)
```

invoking the UDTF:

```
select index,current_value,PRODUCT as cumulative_product
from sample_numbers,table(CUMULATIVE_PRODUCT(current_value) over ())
```

[image]

Note the [empty over() clause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html#explicit-partitioning-with-an-empty-over-clause) which forces Snowflake to do a single sequential run over the data instead of splitting it into parallel chunks